# StreamResource вставляет разделитель "+" между словами(Vaadin)

Tags: java, vaadin, separator

При попытке сохранить отчет на компьютер, в названии файлов вместо пробела проставляется сепаратор "+". Подскажите что можно сделать?

```
StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, table.getCaption()+new Date().toString()+".xls");
                resource.getStream().setParameter("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + table.getCaption()+".xls" + "\"");
                resource.setMIMEType("application/xls");
```

Создается файл с таким названием:

> Ваши+заявкиThu+Jun+01+15-11-12+MSK+2017